# Calculate correlation matrix using SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, correlation

Given sample table with some values like this:

| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 15 | 13 | 12 | 21 |
| 14 | 23 | 41 | 57 | 13 |
| 23 | 41 | 57 | 13 | 39 |
| 90 | 81 | 32 | 76 | 78 |

Our goal is to create correlation matrix using SQL in Oracle.

The result table should be like this:

| # | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 0.968627486 | -0.023590701 | 0.723566409 | 0.962065691 |
| a2 | 0.968627486 | 1 | 0.214217652 | 0.655979092 | 0.974931214 |
| a3 | -0.023590701 | 0.214217652 | 1 | 0.009891122 | 0.079502115 |
| a4 | 0.723566409 | 0.655979092 | 0.009891122 | 1 | 0.524414529 |
| a5 | 0.962065691 | 0.974931214 | 0.079502115 | 0.524414529 | 1 |

I have try some formula for calculate correlation coefficient of two values, but it can't help. Also correlation function doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CORR` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CORR.html):

```sql
WITH ordered (rn, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 FROM table_name
)
SELECT key,
       CORR(a1, value) AS a1,
       CORR(a2, value) AS a2,
       CORR(a3, value) AS a3,
       CORR(a4, value) AS a4,
       CORR(a5, value) AS a5
FROM   ordered t
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT *
         FROM   ordered
         UNPIVOT (
           value FOR key IN (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
         )
       ) d
       ON (t.rn = d.rn)
GROUP BY key
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) AS
SELECT 12, 15, 13, 12, 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 23, 41, 57, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 41, 57, 13, 39 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 90, 81, 32, 76, 78 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | KEY | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A1 | 1 | .9686274863493618022648973908306711860158 | -.0235907009791586343670275607353945975836 | .7235664093128934907375377255687028401814 | .9620656911630149496690023500551903300058 |
> | A2 | .9686274863493618022648973908306711860158 | 1 | .2142176524658728558977962209541976877097 | .655979092200627387045632202651644194262 | .9749312135706365317565525851529784515689 |
> | A3 | -.0235907009791586343670275607353945975836 | .2142176524658728558977962209541976877097 | 1 | .009891122282267634886059354456616140169476 | .079502115405919407497390073647822157651 |
> | A4 | .7235664093128934907375377255687028401814 | .655979092200627387045632202651644194262 | .009891122282267634886059354456616140169476 | 1 | .5244145293486588849105425925771231892634 |
> | A5 | .9620656911630149496690023500551903300058 | .9749312135706365317565525851529784515689 | .079502115405919407497390073647822157651 | .5244145293486588849105425925771231892634 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=033493f5c8731bc02c695e30dcd9986e)*